# Android Retrofit: Response 200 in both release and debug version but release version have empty value returned

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using the latest Retrofit version and followed the [tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-creating-a-sustainable-android-client) here on setting up my Retrofit. In the debug version of my Android app, everything works perfectly fine. I could get data from the calls I make in the app. However, when I tried to do the same in my release apk, response is 200 but data is null. I've been searching all over the net for the solution but couldn't find any.

Comment: any proguard ???

Comment: I don't think so. But it would be great if you can tell me where and what to look for inside proguard

Comment: show proguard-rules.pro

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya no rules are being used inside

Answer (score 0):

So I just decided to set **minifyEnabled** to **false** and to my surprise, it works fine. I'm not sure if this is an ideal solution but I am willing to hear other solutions as well.

Comment: I don't think it's an ideal solution.