# After building release version Retrofit2 gets 200 but empty data

Tags: android, proguard, minify

I got this quesetion: [Android Retrofit: Response 200 in both release and debug version but release version have empty value returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61046155/android-retrofit-response-200-in-both-release-and-debug-version-but-release-ver)

But I don't think this is an ideal solution. But this gave me an idea that this is related to Proguard Set up.

I've already check if the data from server coming incorrectly. But it comes the same and fine. My gradle setting related Proguard is like this:

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

And the proguard-rules file doesn't have any lines for exceptions.

And I am going to change it to this. includes `shrinkResources` attribute:

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

How can I receive data correctly even after enabling proguard?

Comment: did you get correct data in debug mode?

Comment: @ShaluTD Yes. It works fine in debug mode.

Comment: Can I see your full app gradle file? also the data you returned in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with keeping model's data names.

wrote this line into `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-keep class com.example.model.* // model is package name.
```

or if you are using androidX. you can use `@Keep` annotation.

```
@Keep
class YourItem(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int?
    ){
}
```